# Accidentally installed Rails under sudo without RVM. How to move Rails installation and gems to RVM without breaking applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sudo

So I wish I had known far before that installing Rails with `sudo` was a bad thing. In fact, after doing my research, it appears that most people would agree that installing any type of package manager as `sudo` is a big no-no.

Unfortunately for me, I found this out a bit too late. I have several Rails applications that I have created and I am worried that If I try to reinstall Rails with RVM that my applications will not work because of dependency issues.

When I would install gems with `bundle install`, if the gem was new, Rails would ask for my password before installing it. I did not think much of it at the time, but now, I am worried nothing will work after I try booting a Rails app.

So my questions are:

- If I installed Rails with `sudo`, will my applications still work if I reinstalled it under RVM?
- If they don't work, what would I need to make them function correctly?
- How do I remove a Rails installation that was installed with `sudo`?
- Is this issue as severe as I think it is?

I had seen a lot of related posts about why one should not use `sudo` to install gems and Rails in general, as well as why not to do it with RVM, and pretty much not to do it all with anything Ruby related. But I have not seen a post that really addresses any of my concerns and questions that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not severe as you think. Applications are meant to be portable (somewhat), once you have the same dependencies installed as your development machine, they are meant to work again otherwise you wouldn't be able to deploy.

Now the main thing to check is that all your files in your rails applications are owned by user and not by sudo (otherwise you won't be able to read them later on).
Aside from it, you can simply install rvm, ensure with `which ruby` and `which gem` comes from rvm and not from your packaged ruby installation (which you **can remove**, I do this usually) and then simply run bundle install in your rails application, at that point they are ready to start again.

Comment: And if files within the Rails application aren't owned by the user, you can `chown -R` them all.

Comment: Nice. This is helpful. So essentially I just remove my current Rails installation, and with RVM already installed, I just run `bundle install` and RVM will intercept it and "reorganize" my gems correctly?

Comment: Rvm will intercept executables (gem, ruby, bundler etc) and will use the ones in rvm. SO yes, it will (reinstall, not reorganize) reorganize your gems correctly